# Making -net install- command from display output clickable

Tags: stata

I want to use `display` to show as an output a 'clickable' `net install` command. However, the `https` link forces Stata to split the command into two parts: before and after the colon `:`.

In the end, the output window shows a text `//sites.google.com/site/rdpackages/rdrobust/stata) replace` which redirects me to `net install rdrobust, from(https`.

Example:

```
* command 
display as input "{net install rdrobust, from(https://sites.google.com/site/rdpackages/rdrobust/stata) replace}"

* output
//sites.google.com/site/rdpackages/rdrobust/stata) replace
```

I assume an escape symbol can fix that but multiple trials and personal research did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
. display `"{stata "net install rdrobust, from(https://sites.google.com/site/rdpackages/rdrobust/stata) replace"}"'
net install rdrobust, from(https://sites.google.com/site/rdpackages/rdrobust/stata) replace
```